# Physical understanding of the change in scattering cross-sections at finite temperatures

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, scattering, thermal-field-theory

I am familiar with the computation of scattering cross-sections in zero temperature quantum field theory.

*How does a scattering cross-section typically behave at temperature $T$?*

Let the cross-section of a scattering process at a finite temperature $T$ be denoted by $\sigma(T)$, and the same process at zero temperature be denoted by $\sigma(0)$. *My question is whether* $\sigma(T)>\sigma(0)$,   $\sigma(T)<\sigma(0)$ *or*  $\sigma(T)=\sigma(0)$? How can we understand it physically?

Comment: What reason do you have to believe this can be said in generality, and does not depend on specifics of the system (i.e. some amplitudes go up, others go down with increasing temperature)? Unless you can give an argument why the behaviour with rising temperature should be universal, this question seems very broad.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This question came to my mind from the answer here by lurscher https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375150/why-did-dark-matter-interact-with-the-standard-model-particles-in-the-early-univ

Comment: That answer merely states that the cross section of dark matter with other matter *may* be higher at higher energies. It doesn't tell you what model of dark matter is being used, or whether it is indeed based on any explicit model or merely speculation. The correct way to ask about an unfounded and vague answer is to comment on said answer, not to ask an equally unfounded and vague question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is a macroscopic measure, it is statistical , a thermodynamic variable.

At best, an ensemble of particles with a statistical distribution of energy in a thermodynamic equilibrium will have a  *kinetic* temperature defined as

[image: temp]

connected with the [average kinetic energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html) of the ensemble of particles.

On the other hand, the scattering cross section is defined for two particles scattering off each other at a time.

This scattering is usually calculated at the center of mass system. If the experiment is done in a different system the energy of the particles scattering off each other should be taken into account, transforming it into the cms to see the probability of scatter according to the calculation.

The only way your question can make sense is if one is talking of the scattering cross section in a gas of  hydrogen for example, scattering off each other with the kinetic energy distributions given by the temperature.

There is not σ(0) or σ(T), there is one calculation of the crossection. Higher temperature in inter gas scatterings will mean higher crossection, if the basic particle+particle crossection rises with energy; so in a hotter gas the atoms will have a higher energy of scattering on average ,than for a colder gas, so the scattering off each other will be more probable in higher temperatures.

For gases like [plasma](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/plasma.html) the temperature is important because a phase change happens as a function of temperature, but again it has to do with statistical, thermodynamic considerations on the basic crossections of particles involved, which are invariant at the center of mass of the two particles involved.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is correct. [Thermal quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_quantum_field_theory) is certainly a thing, and it appears quite sensible to me to be able to ask whether the crosssections (in the sense of QFT, i.e. the n-point functions of the field operators) go up or down with temperature. The problem of the question is not the temperature, but that it doesn't specify an explicit theory in which one could compute these crosssections and therefore definitively answer it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  there is no two particle crossection σ discussed in the article . it is a different formalism. a QFT can be defined on very many levels, two particle crossection is a very well defined calculation in the appropriate QFT.

Comment: @annav An an intuitive level, your answer seems plausible.